# use nodejs to query mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use mysql module [nodejs-mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql)
I have two tables, Their struct is like this:

Table nicks

```
id   |nick   |
--------------
1    |Arnold |
2    |Bob    |
```

Table order

```
nick   |money |
---------------
Arnold |12    |
Arnold |43    |
Arnold |3     |
Bob    |32    |
Bob    |2     |
```

I want get a json object whose struct is like this:

```
[
   {id:1, nick:'Arnold', order:[{money:12},{money:43},{money:3}]},
   {id:2, nick:'Bob', order[{money:32},{money:2}]}
]
```

so what should I do?I use nodejs

what I have try:

```
   var mysql      = require('mysql');
   var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'example.org',
      db       : 'db'
      user     : 'user',
      password : 'secret'
   });
   connection.connect();
   connection.query('select * from nicks',function(err,data){
       //here I travese the data array,and select the order table to get the money filed data.

   });
```

I know how to create a query with node.js, I just don't know a method to get the results I want.I don't know how to make a proper query.

Comment: You can't declare such object `{money:12,money:43,money:3}` in Javascript. Each of member a object should be unique.

Comment: sorry, I have corrected it.

Comment: which one is your server side language?

Comment: I use node.js, and I use [node-mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) as my db driver

Comment: What have you done? You say you use node-mysql but you just want the code without saying your problem.

Comment: Sorry for that,I have complete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn  = mysql.createConnection({
  host      : 'localhost',
  database  : 'test',
});

var query = ' \
SELECT id, nicks.nick, GROUP_CONCAT(money) AS money \
FROM nicks, orders \
WHERE orders.nick = nicks.nick \
GROUP BY id';

conn.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.order = row.money.toString().split(',').map(function(value) {
      return { money : Number(value) };
    });
    delete row.money;
  });
  // as an example, we'll print the object as JSON
  console.log(JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It's a feasible method, but is there a way I can do it completely?

Comment: What do you mean by 'completely'?

Comment: I mean 'directly', is there a method that I can query the stucts I want without split strings?

Comment: @Arnold I don't think MySQL supports that, so in that case you'd have to leave out the `GROUP BY id` clause and parse the results yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the documentation at https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql
You need to setup a connection and query the db

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

var queryString = "SELECT * FROM nicks n JOIN order o ON n.nick=o.nick";
connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows) {
  var outputJSON = [];
  for row in rows{
    outputJSON.push(row);
  }
  return outputJSON.toJSON()
});
```

You need to implement the function toJSON that formats your output by picking only the desired fields you need for you JSON

Comment: Did not answer the question of trying to get the joined rows into the single record row.